# Payment on 2 Stripe Accounts

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

Hi I just wanted to ask can I make 2 payments on stripe using codeigniter?

I will be using 2 separate accounts of stripe.

I have both live keys & test keys of both account. Just wanted to ask can I create 2 APIs in one application?

I don't wanted to use stripe connect feature.

Comment: With stripe-php you can specify which API key you are using per call, so you can manage two account keys within the same app. https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication?lang=php

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do with two payments? Do you want to do two separate payments at separate time or are you looking to have two accounts get paid for the same transaction?

Comment: @Pompey I want to charge my customer $100 and from backend I want to split payment in 2 accounts. On A account I want to receive $20, and on B account I want to receive $80. 

This is the whole thing.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use Stripe Connect for that? That flow would be fairly easy to do with Connect. Without it, you will need to collect your user's payment information two separate times and then make each charge separately (which would also incur a Stripe fee twice).

Comment: It might be worth writing in to Stripe's support to discuss your business case, they can help direct you with their products. https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true